# How to prove that $A$ can be diagonalized?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $A$ be a linear operator in ${\rm I\!R^n}$ such that $A^2$ = $\lambda A$.

I know that what is a diagonalizable matrix but I can't understand here how to use this concept to find it.

Can someone will help me to show that   $A$ can be diagonalized for
$\lambda \neq$ 0.

One more interesting question that is it true if $\lambda$ = 0?}

Comment: What is the minimal polynomial of $A$?

Comment: (Doesn't solve your problem)
Note that if $A^2 = \lambda A$ then $A$ is singular ($det(A)=0$). Because $A^2 = \lambda A \Rightarrow A(A- \lambda I) = 0 \Rightarrow det(A)\cdot \det(A - \lambda I) = 0$ since the second determinant is the characteristic polynomial (not always zero) it follows that $det(A)=0$

Comment: Thanks @HugoValadão. Yes, I understand these things but in general, how will we prove it that A can be diagonalized where $A^2$ = $A\lambda$ for non-negative $\lambda$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: the null spaces of $A$ and of $A - \lambda I$ span $\mathbb R^n$.

It's not true if $\lambda=0$: e.g. consider $$\pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 0 & 0\cr}$$.

Comment: thank you só much for your guidelines. Yes, it makes sense that the null spaces span my whole space. But is that sufficient to show that linear operator $A$ will be diagonalizable?

Comment: Yes: take a basis consisting of a basis of the null space of $A$ and a basis of the null space of $A-\lambda I$, and the matrix in that basis is diagonal.

Comment: Yes, I got it and but here, I don't know the matrix $A$, its entities which makes it difficult for me to find its basis. May you please help me?

Comment: If I take A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix} then $\lambda= 1,1$ Am I doing right?

Comment: You don't know $A$, but you do know the matrix for $A$ **in the basis that I told you**.